# Killing a Process in a Running Docker Container

Tags: docker

I have a server-side application running in a Docker container. One of the processes in it has hung and needs to be killed (the application will then spawn another process to replace it).

Is there any way to kill that process without stopping the Docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with Docker for now, but seems to be scheduled for 0.8, see issue #1228 [here](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1228).

It is however possible to use lxc-attach to run a shell in an existing container (seen in the above issue comments) and you then can kill your hung process from there :

```
 $ lxc-attach -n FULLCONTAINERID /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks ometra. This issue seems to be about running another command on an existing running container - very useful and a somewhat more general case.

I actually ended up solving this by finding the hung process on the docker host and killing it from there directly, without lxc-attach-ing bash to the container. Your answer will work too though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the FULLCONTAINERID with docker ps --no-trunc=true :

> root@turmes /home/zoobab [35]# docker ps --no-trunc=true
>   CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                    > COMMAND                                                                   C     STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
>   2741d88a51148e66d7b2b44d8c1cc6ed7d1515f370be5d00bd003d40cf8d575b   zoobab/centos57:latest   kamailio -P /var/run/kamailio.pid -m 64 -M 4 -u kamailio -g kamailio -D   1     Up 19 minutes                           angry_fermat
>   root@turmes /home/zoobab [36]#

Answer (score 1):

If running Docker 1.3 or newer is not an option, you can still obtain access to a root shell inside the Docker Container using [nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter).

[This](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2014/01/27/access-a-container-without-ssh/) blog post has all the instructions you need.

Once you have root shell access, you can of course perform any operation you like.

Answer (score 1):

maybe times have changed but as of docker.latest:
`docker kill 593690fe0087` killed the `CONTAINER ID` when I ran `docker ps`. I had a container there for 2 weeks and only saw it now when the environment wasn't up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now in Docker 1.3 using the [`exec` command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec):

```
docker exec container_name kill process_name
```

Comment: I used the same command as you said . But i could not kill the process. when i type "docker top container_name ", i can still see the process.  What can I do now?